# Getting 404 error for CSS, Image and JS files in tomcat live/production server

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, static-resource

I have launched a new site www.example.com (real name hidden). i had upload basic web project which will have a index.html file, css, js, images and WEB-INF folder with web.xml file inside.
I named project as simpleProject, i placed the project folder in /opt/myapps/, 
I did necessary configurations like 
1. adding IP & domainname in **/etc/hosts** file
2. adding **<HOST>...</HOST>** in /etc/tomcat7/server.xml file and
3. placed **ROOT.xml** file with one line **<context docBase="/opt/myapps/simpleProject" path="" ......... />** in **/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/Catalina/www.example.com/**.

when i hit www.example.com the index.html page is getting served but the css and images defined in the page is not coming, **throwing 404 error** for those. I used even the context path like "http://www.example.com/css/style.css".

Comment: check the server error log and maybe it will say where it's trying to find the missing files

Comment: where could i find the logs, it is a basic web application i didn't configured log4j logger to it. Could you plz help me in finding the logging files

Comment: you should look at the catalina<date>.out files. As for where to find it, that depends on how tomcat got installed. I would simply search for all files named catalina*out

Comment: Hi, i checked into the logs. There is no error shown. I think there could be two cases, one is improper context definitions and second could be firewall.
In root.xml i had defined context only till the root structure <context docBase="/opt/myapps/project_name" path="" reloadable="true">. will this server for css and js files too?

Comment: Issue is fixed, the reason is file access permissions. i changed the chmod to 777 to all static files. It is working good now. Thanks alot everyone